# Display encoded character python 3 on debian

Tags: python

I would like to display the Multiplication sign on my consol with Python3.

His hexa code is D8 and he is encoding with ISO 8859-1 but all tests are negative.

Thanks for your help.

```
print(×) #(work on mac, doesn't work on debian)
```

I also try unicode('\xd7', errors='ignore') but nothing

(Sorry for my bad english)

EDIT: I also tried

```
b'\xd7'.decode('ISO-8859-1')
```

but nothing

Answer (score 0):

No problem on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
$ cat /tmp/x.py 
print("×")
$ python3.4 /tmp/x.py 
×
```

Comment: When I want to c/c the "×" character, I cant. Replace by "?^?".